# Width of element in DataGridTextColumn.Header

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

Please help how to stretch the width of the text box in the DataGridTextColumn.Header to the entire length.

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BColumn" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="20">
                            <TextBlock Text="B" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontStyle="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                                             
                                     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Link for application window:
https://ibb.co/KjRhCPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch` on `DataGridColumnHeader`. Here is how you do it through a style:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

You need to add this style in `DataGrid.Resources`.

And, then you need to use `Grid` for your `Header` content instead of `StackPanel` as `Grid` takes up the whole available space and `StackPanel` doesn't

Here is the full XAML:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BColumn" Width="*">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <Grid MinWidth="20">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="B" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontStyle="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                                             
                             VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```